# Compare two columns of a table with a specific value; If one matches, return the other one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this following model in my application, which is related to another model in multiple ways

```
class XYZRelated < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :xyz1, class_name: 'XYZ', foreign_key: 'xyz1_id'
    belongs_to :xyz2, class_name: 'XYZ', foreign_key: 'xyz2_id'
end
```

In addition, I have validations in place that make sure that `xyz1_id != xyz2_id`, and that every combination of two IDs `[xyz1_id, xyz2_id]` is unique even if the IDs were exchanged, i.e. having a row `[3,1]` means that no other row is allowed with `[1,3]`.

For a JSON API, I wish to be able to search the related model for one XYZ_ID, and return the other ID as efficiently as possible.

However, I do not know if the ID I am searching for is stored in xyz1_id or xyz2_id. As such, I wish to compare an arbitrary ID with both xyz1_id and xyz2_id, and if it matches one column, i'd return the other one (unless the other one is NULL, in which case i'd not return the match).

Currently I'm doing this:

```
def find_all_ids(xyz_id)
    l = XYZRelated.where(xyz1_id: xyz_id).where.not(xyz2_id: nil)
                  .pluck(:xyz2_id).to_a
    l.concat XYZRelated.where(xyz2_id: xyz_id).where.not(xyz1_id: nil)
                       .pluck(:xyz1_id).to_a
    return l
end
```

I assume there is a better way of doing this, or maybe even a better way of laying out the database in order to avoid this issue. However, I'm not very familiar with advanced SQL querying, and I cannot find anything in the Rails documentation.

How could I do this more efficiently, in order to avoid the two separate queries and concatenation of the results? Thank you!

Comment: what'd happen if the id is present in both xyz1_id and xyz2_id ? and XYZ has_many / has_one ?

Comment: I've got a validation that makes sure that case never happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two separate queries and you can use UNION to combine them but i am not very sure about the perf difference between **firing individual queries vs 
UNION**.

The following makes it significantly simpler

```
XYZRelated.where("xyz1_id = :xyz_id OR xyz2_id = :xyz_id", xyz_id: xyz_id)
          .pluck(:xyz1_id, :xyz2_id).uniq.compact - [xyz_id]
```

**Explanation -**

> 1. Query for all records which has either xyz1_id or xyz2_id set to xyz_id
> 2. flatten the array (2d array to 1d array)
> 3. remove duplicates (about half the array would be xyz_id since every matching record will have at least one id = xyz_id)
> 4. remove NULL entry (so that you don't have to care about the "other" id being NULL)
> 5. then remove the input param **xyz_id** since it will obviously be in the array

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've got a validation that makes sure that xyz1_id != xyz2_id in all cases. I've got another validation that makes it so that every `[xyz1_id, xyz2_id]` combination is unique, even if xyz1_id and xyz2_id are exchanged, as such there is no need for the `uniq` call.
I'll wait a bit to see if someone has know how to do it using UNION (and whether there'd be any perf. improvement), but if not, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: yeah. in that case, flatten would be unnecessary. editing the solution

Comment: I'll edit the question to reflect the constraints as well

Comment: but i think you don't need UNION in this case. the most efficient way to do this is to do a single select with a where clause. I'd interested to know if combining two queries/union would be better as well..

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I'm curious about one thing, wouldn't it be more efficient to check for the NULL during the query to avoid the `compact` call? Especially considering the fact that the DB has indexes on `xyz1_id`, `xyz2_id` and `[xyz1_id, xyz2_id]`?
So, we'd use `XYZRelated.where("(xyz1_id = :xyz_id OR xyz2_id = :xyz_id) AND (NOT (xyz1_id IS NULL OR xyz2_id IS NULL))", xyz_id: xyz_id).pluck(:xyz1_id, :xyz2_id).uniq - [xyz_id]`

Comment: One small thing I just noticed, you're missing a `flatten`call in your answer, without which the whole thing doesn't work.